# Gazebo 1.2.5 gets really slow after spawning some simple models. [fixed]

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-1.2

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

After spawning some simple models (sdf v1.2) (spatula, mug, table) in Gazebo 1.2.5, the program and the computer gets really slow, although the real time factor stays at 1.0.

Gazebo 1.0.2 worked without any problems using the same models (sdf v1.0) with a real time factor greater than 6.0 .

Ideas?

Thanks,
Andrei

UPDATE: I guess it was some hardware issue, because now it started working fine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/492/gazebo-1.2.5-gets-really-slow-after-spawning-some-simple-models.-%5Bfixed%5D/) by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 2108 on 2012-12-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This looks resolved.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2012-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0